# Salesforce Login Email Verification in SaucelabsVM

Tags: java, salesforce, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

We'd like to setup some test automation around our SalesForce instance using SauceLabs.  We'd like to keep it independent of the salesforce instance itself as we have a dedicated continuous integration server which drives all our automation across several integration points in our system (of which SalesForce is one).  Because of this requirement, SauceForce won't quite suit our needs.

I have successfully setup a Selenium test that hits our SalesForce instance via SauceLabs but the problem is that because the browser is running from a VM in the SauceLabs cloud that SalesForce does not recognise, it prompts for an email verification code.  This is a blocker for us as the workaround would be too cumbersome.  I asked some developers - they suggested adding the VM IP address to a list of exceptions but unfortunately, SauceLabs assigns VM IPs dynamically so we are therefore unable to define an IP range in Salesforce for security exceptions to bypass the email verification prompt.

I am curious as to how SauceForce gets around this problem - does anyone have insight in this regard?please give response how to login in salesforce in saucelabs?

Answer (score 1):

Having just been round the houses trying to fix this myself I thought I'd post an update here:

Firstly: Salesforce won't disable this feature (there is implication they may have done so in the past but they now don't; we even escalated through premium support and direct with senior account managers but no joy)

Try using SauceLabs Connect: Saucelabs have built a kind of proxy tunnel server that is actually designed to facilitate testing of intranet sites (where access to the servers is likely only allowed from internal IP addresses).  Starting a Saucelabs connect agent configured against your Salesforce org will mean all Saucelabs traffic goes through this proxy and you can then whitelist the IP that this agent is running on.  This of course means you need somewhere static to run the agent (we us a cloud VM).  More on Sauce Connect here: https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can log a case with Salesforce and they can turn it off.